# Regex to find expressions whose every odd or even character is some character

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a string is composed such that every second character is `e` (or space), starting either at any of index 0 or 1.

I am unfamiliar with regex enough to come up with something as even a start.

Accepted strings:

```
Aebece
Aebec
eAebec
eAebece
e
eAe
Aeb
```

Rejected

```
A
Ab
Aeeb
Aeee
ee
eee
eeAebec
eA

Aaebbecce
Aaebbecc
(And so on, meaning each of a,b,c can NOT be a word of any length not containing `e`, but has to be a single character)
```

I believe this defines it, but surely someone will run into an edge case that didn't occur to me.

I used 'e' instead of space for visual ease.
In plain english, this is supposed to catch "space separated words" such as
"W o W", "S W E E T " and so on, but not sentences such as "H O L Y  S M O K E S" (notice double space).

I hope this is clear.

Comment: I think you would have to do even and odd separately. As a starting point: "^(.e)+$"

Comment: ^e?(([^e]e)+[^e]?)?$

Comment: If a single `e` is allowed, so should `eA` also allowed ?

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/wa8362/2) what you want?

Comment: @Toto posted ^(?:e|e?[a-df-z](?:e[a-df-z])+e?)$, it is great but it seems to miss eAe

Comment: @user_na: You're rigth, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Are `A` & `eA` really rejected?

Comment: [Suggestion updated](https://regex101.com/r/wa8362/4), is it OK?

Comment: @Toto great solution, at least it does fit all requirements. If it is ok for you I will copy it to my answer to preserve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way of doing this would be to *extract* both even and odd characters in two separate arrays, collapse the arrays, and verify their length:

```
''.join(set("H O L Y S M O K E S"[1::2])) (without double space)
```

returns " ", a single space.

```
''.join(set("H O L Y  S M O K E S"[1::2])) (without double space)
```

returns " EKMOS".

The problem will lie in multibyte characters, when the "[1::2]" trick will not work (I don't think it will work with regex either, because `re.findall(r'(.)', "Cioè")` yields `['C', 'i', 'o', '\xc3', '\xa8']` instead of `[ 'C', 'i', 'o', 'è' ]`).

## Regex

If you need a regex, then:

```
^(?:(?:[ e].)*[ e]?|(?:.[ e])*.?)$
```

This means that between the beginning and the end of the string there must be either `(?:[ e].)*[ e]?` (a "space/e plus anything" pair), repeated, optionally followed by one space/e); *or* `(?:.[ e])*.?`, a whatever followed by space/e, possibly repeated, optionally followed by a character.

This is not exactly equivalent to your request because it will accept a word separated by **both** spaces and e's: "HeOeL Y S M O K EeS" is good. To have *either* all spaces *or* all e's, you need

```
^(?:(?: .)* ?|(?:. )*.?)|(?:.e)*.?)|(?:e.)e?)$
```

to cover the four cases (space-separated beginning at 0, at 1, e-separated at 0, and e-separated at 1).

Comment: Not using regex is indeed more convenient, but my framework forces my hand to use regex.

Comment: Got it. Added a regex solution. This, too, has troubles with UTF-8 and multibyte in general (most regexes have). It is easily extended to more than two (space and e) separators, even if it quickly becomes awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an inconsistency in your request.
Allowed strings

```
A_B_C
A_B_C_
_A_
_A_B_C
```

But not allowed are:

```
A
_A
```

From a pattern point of view `A` is very similar to `A_B_C` and `_A` is very similar to `_A_B_C`.
With also including `A` and `_A` the best regexp I can come up with is

```
^\s?(?:\w\s)*[\w\s]?$
```

In words: start of string, 0 or 1 white-space, 0 or more character-space blocks, followed by a single character or a single white-space followed by end of string.

You could additionaly check that it does not match `^\s{0,1}\w$` to exclude the two cases above if this is really your intention. It also matches to __ so you need to also check that the string is not exactly 2 space characters.

[UPDATE]

There is a great regexp in the comments which works perfectly - (all credits to Toto)

```
^(?!.*ee)(?!.*[a-df-z]{2,})(?!e?[a-df-z]$)\w+$
```

[UPDATE2]

This one matches also arbitrary whit spaces and letters:

```
^(?!\s\s(?<!\n))(?!\s?\w$)\s?(?:\w\s)*[\w\s]?$
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful, however I don't want to limit only to English. How can I extend this to work for any character (space or `e` separated)?

Comment: \s is already matching any whitespace, \w any word like. My version is already matching special charaters see: https://regex101.com/r/pBwk4e/2/ .

Comment: Accepted @LSerni's answer as I find it more readable. I feel bad because both are correct. Have to only select one though :(